# Is there a complex example graph database available?

Tags: arangodb

We are currently developing a web tool which lets you interface and query your database. Which then can display the results in different graph visualisations.

Currently we use the airports example but we would like to test with a more complex database with multiple node and edge collections. Are there import files available for such databases?